# Find a homotopy between $f,g: S^1 \to S^1$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Given two continuous function $f,g:S^1 \to S^1$ such that $f(x) \neq g(x) \forall x\in S^1$, I have to prove that $f$ and $g$ are homotopic.

So, I have to find a homotopy $$F: S^1 \times [0,1] \longrightarrow S^1 \\(x,0) \mapsto f(x) \\(x,1) \mapsto g(x)$$

Is it right to choose $$F: S^1 \times [0,1] \longrightarrow S^1 \\ (x,t) \mapsto \frac{tf(x)+(1-t)g(x)}{\vert\vert{tf(x)+(1-t)g(x)}\vert\vert} ?$$ In this case I don't understand why the two functions need to be different $\forall x$.

Have you any idea?

Comment: It is necessary that $\vert\vert{tf(x)+(1-t)g(x)}\vert\vert\ne 0$

Comment: It is basically the same homotopy that shows that any map $f:S^n \to S^n$ that does not have a fixed point is homotopic to the antipodal map.  What changes do you have to make?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the previous comments, the homotopy provided in the question is not correct because the segment in the denominator passes through zero.

So I could use the homotopy $$F: S^1 \times [0,1] \longrightarrow S^1 \\ (x,t) \mapsto \frac{f(x)(1+e^{i\pi t})-g(x)(e^{i\pi t}-1)}{\parallel f(x)(1+e^{i\pi t})-g(x)(e^{i\pi t}-1)\parallel}.$$